# Update records updated in Flexcard Datatable

Tags: datatable, omnistudio, integration-procedure

I want to replace the Opportunity related list component on the Account record page with a Flexcard that has a datatable element listing all the related Opportunity records.

I am aware that this use case is not best practise, but I use it to practise my Omnistudio skills.

I also want to restrict this example to the Flexcard only and use the Flexcard's native functionality to update these record.

I am able to display all the related Opportunity records in the datatable using an Integration Procedure that receives the `AccountId` and retrieves all related Opportunities.

The issue I encounter is updating these records when they are changed on the datatable:

[image]

The Salesforce Help files [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_flexcards_datatable_properties_29884.htm&type=5) lists a datatable event `update` that "Fires when table data changes."

I also found a very thorough Quip document going through all the datatable event use cases [here](https://exah.quip.com/ftaxAqKJknkj/FlexCards-data-table-events).

I created an event listener that triggers on the 'update' event and passes the information to an Integration Procedure that updates the relevant record:

[image]

I assumed from the Quip document that the updated values will also be contained in the `{action.result.FIELD_NAME}` and as such I pass these merge fields to the IP.

From my GIF above, it seems like not to do the job, so my question is how to I pass the updated values to the IP to update the records OR is it even required to do such a thing with the 'update' event as from the Salesforce documentation as well as the Quip file it is not immediately obvious.

Should I rather use another event such as `rowclick` or `selectrow`?

I have created an MVP of the Flexcard which you can download [here](https://github.com/sfadriaan/Stack-Exchange-Questions/tree/main/418808).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the `update` event will not work for this scenario. I created a flexcard that basically showcases what each datable event does:

[image]

A summary of each event that I tested:

- `rowclick` captures the row column values with `{action.result.FIELD_NAME}`. You can click anywhere on the row and it will return that row's information. In the GIF you can see how the `recordId` gets updated for "Clicked On RecordId"
- `selectrow` returns the last selected row's details and each field's value can be accessed with `{action.result.FIELD_NAME}`.
- `update` fires when the data in the datatable changes. It does not return the values of the row that was updated, or the updated `{records}` merge field

An interesting thing I picked up is that the `{records}` list does not get updated when you update a cell value in the datatable.

Also, I added in the event listener for `rowclick` to write the row values to `Session.FIELD_NAME`, but when I update a value and press the checkmark for row level edit (or click out of the cell I just updated for cell level edit), the updated value does not get written to its designated place.

This lets me assume that you actually cannot commit any changes made in the datatable to the database with the datatable alone.

As such I used the `rowclick` event to write the `recordId` to `Session.Id` and then launch a flyout Omniscript. The OS uses the `recordId` to get the relevant fields for that `recordId` and displays it for editing by the user. The user can then make the changes, save the record and the flexcard gets reloaded to display the newest changes:

[image]

My conclusion is thus:

- **Flexcards** are used to display data and enables a user to take certain actions (such as click on a record to edit it, or press a button to launch an Omniscript).
- **Omniscripts** are used to guide the user through a process which can be capturing/updating information.